# Pseudo element inclusions not working for Font Awesome

Tags: css, font-face, pseudo-element, webfonts

**Edit: this problem is specific to pseudo element inclusions of Font Awesome, `<i class="fas fa-spray-can"></i>` works fine.**  However,

```
 #menu-item-3218 a:before{
    content:'\f5bd';
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    display:inline-block!important;
    padding-right:6px;
    vertical-align:-5%;
    font-size:90%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

does not work.

However, to thicken the plot, that pseudo-element inclusion does work for `font-family: "fa5-brands"`, but not for `font-family: "FontAwesome"`.

As you can see, the font icons do not load for `font-family: "FontAwesome"` (box placeholders appear instead) but do load for `font-family: "fa5-brands"` (the PS4 icon, etc.) and `font-family: 'Rajdhani'` (the text font you see):
[image]

In Chrome developer panel, fonts appear to be loading, I guess?

[image]

**Location of CSS stylesheet:**
[image: Location of CSS stylesheet]

**Location of fonts:**
[image: Location of fonts]

I can't find any error in my implementation of @font-face in the css stylesheet on my WordPress website.  Can someone see something wrong that I can't?

**Relevant content in CSS stylesheet:**

```
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'Rajdhani';
     src: url('./assets/fonts/Rajdhani/rajdhani-regular-webfont.svg#rajdhaniregular') format('svg'), url('./assets/fonts/Rajdhani/rajdhani-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/Rajdhani/rajdhani-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
}
 @font-face {
     font-family: "fa5-brands";
     src: url('./assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5-2-0-web/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome-free') format('svg'), url('./assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5-2-0-web/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5-2-0-web/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5-2-0-web/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
}
 @font-face {
     font-family: "FontAwesome";
     src: url('./assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5-2-0-web/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome-free') format('svg'), url('./assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5-2-0-web/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5-2-0-web/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff') format('woff'), url('./assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5-2-0-web/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Are the font-files loaded? (Check in the browsers dev-tools.) Can the icon-font bes used at all? Or is it an error in using the icons and applying them via HTML class names?

Comment: Why add it in your own stylesheet when you can just load them from the web. You won't have a problem that way

Comment: @feeela - sorry if I wasn't clear enough - yes, not loading essentially - or box placeholders loading where the fonts should load.  Question edited to show this.

Comment: @feeela - I have edited question to include a screenshot of developer panel in Chrome, showing the fonts all have 200 status.

Comment: @SuperDJ I'm afraid it badly affects SEO ratings, adding another request, and causes search engine scores to tank.  I also don't like being dependent on other servers than mine.